# How to execute veracrypt on the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

How can execute veracrypt on the command line in OS X?

According to the [Veracrypt documentation](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20Line%20Usage) there should be a command `veracrypt` but it was not found.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is `/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt`

Comment: Don't know who/why the downvote. This **is** how to use VeraCrypt from the command line on MacOS.

Comment: I did not downvote, but in my opinion this answer misses the "--text" option. Without it, the GUI will be displayed. Troy Liu's answer gives this useful advice

Answer (score 5):

you should append `--text` parameter to `VeraCrypt`

like `/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt --text`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer executes the binary which launches the GUI. This actually gives you the command line interface for managing volumes on the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup a symbolic link named 'veracrypt' to the executable. The following will work in a terminal:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin ; # <<-- if it doesn't exist already
ln -s /Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt ~/bin/veracrypt
```

You can then invoke it to get help with (the -t is for text-only mode):

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" ; # <<-- if not already on your search path
veracrypt -t -h
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify usage, I add this to my .bash_profile:

```
VC="/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt"
```

Then I can execute the app on the command line:

```
$VC --mount /path/to/container
```

Can also define an alias to mount the container:

```
alias mc="$VC --mount /path/to/container"
```